# MongoDB Compass cannot create unique index on string field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I want to enforce unique values on a text column. To do so, I am creating a unique index on said column. This worked for a collection whose field was named "DateTime", but when I try to create a unique index on a field called "Measurement interval=[30sec]", MongoDB Compass refuses to create the unique index with error `22: Invalid argument`.

Both columns have the same type of data. I've been searching for any information on this error but haven't found anything. What am I missing here?

Comment: It's pretty difficult to troubleshoot without the actual command that you attempted. Please update your question to include it (ideally the text of the command rather than a screenshot). And is that literally the field name? If so, maybe try creating the index using the `mongosh` shell directly? That shell is available directly in newer versions of Compass nowadays

Answer (score 0):

When creating unique key, the data already exists on db should not violate unique key constraint. Check if the data for the column have same values to violate unique key constraint. If so, remove those documents and try adding the key again.

Or create a new database with required keys, and then import the data to db.